# Javascript - Error while concatnating objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While executing the below snippet, I'm getting an error stating "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error.

Can someone shed some light here?.

```
var a1={'Param1':'122','Param2':'123','Param3':'124','Param4':'125'};
var b={'Param1':'22','Param2':'23','Param3':'24','Param4':'25'};
var c=a1.concat(b);
```

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: `concat` is defined for Array and String objects in Javascript. JSON doesn't have this defined :)

Comment: @MIdhunKrishna who said anything about `JSON`?

Comment: @MattHarrison I meant `JavaScript Object Literal` or Javascript Object. :) I cant edit my previous comment, else would have corrected it.

Comment: @MIdhunKrishna hehe, no worries. Just feeling pedantic this morning ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a1` is an `object` and javascript `object` does not have a concat method.

Concat is available for strings and arrays

Answer (score 0):

`Object.prototype.concat` is undefined. `concat` is a method on an `array` or `string`.

instead use:

```
for (var attrname in b) { a1[attrname] = b[attrname]; }
```